# How to use variables in sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have file called "text_file1.txt" and the content in the file is 
"subject= /C=US/O=AAA/OU=QA/OU=12345/OU=TESTAPP/"

Now what i want to achieve is to the content to be like below:
"subject= /C=US/O=AAA/$$$QA/###12345/@@@TESTAPP/"

when i execute the below piece of code:

```
#! /bin/ksh
OU1="QA"
OU2=12345
OU3="TESTAPP"
`sed -i "s/OU=$OU1/$$$\${OU1}/g" text_file1.txt`
`sed -i "s/OU=$OU2/###\${OU2}/g" text_file1.txt`
`sed -i "s/OU=$OU3/@@@\${OU3}/g" text_file1.txt`
content=`cat text_file1.txt`
echo "content:$content"
```

i get the output like this:

```
content:subject= /C=US/O=Wells Fargo/2865528655{OU1}/###12345/@@@TESTAPP/CN=03032015_CUST_2131_Unix_CLBLABB34C02.wellsfargo.com
```

only this command "`sed -i "s/OU=$OU1/$$$\${OU1}/g" text_file1.txt`" is not working as expected.Can anyone please suggest some idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can also optimize by writing only 1 sed and separate each `s///` with a `;` after applying the @AvinashRaj solution for your `$` and back tik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help as a start?

```
echo ''
OU1="QA"
echo "subject= /C=US/O=AAA/OU=${OU1}/OU=12345/OU=TESTAPP/" \
| sed -e "s|/OU=${OU1}/|/OU=\$\$\$${OU1}/|g"
```

The result is:

subject= /C=US/O=AAA/OU=$$$QA/OU=12345/OU=TESTAPP/

(You are mixing up the use of $ signs .)

Answer (score 2):

Two things play into this:

1. You have to escape `$` (i.e., use `\$`) in doubly-quoted shell strings if you want a literal `$`, and
2. `\` does not retain its literal meaning when it comes before a `$` inside backticks (that is to say, inside backticks, `\$` becomes just `$`).

When you write

```
`sed -i "s/OU=$OU1/$$$\${OU1}/g" text_file1.txt`
```

because the command is in backticks, you spawn a subshell with the command

```
sed -i "s/OU=$OU1/$$$${OU1}/g" text_file1.txt
```

Since `$$$$` is inside a doubly-quoted string, variable expansion takes place, and it is expanded as two occurrences of `$$` (the process ID of the shell that's doing the expansion). This means that the code `sed` sees is ultimately

```
s/OU=QA/1234512345{OU1}/g
```

...if the process ID of the spawned subshell is `12345`.

In this particular case, you don't need the command substitution (the backticks), so you could write

```
sed -i "s/OU=$OU1/\$\$\$${OU1}/g" text_file1.txt
```

However, using shell variables in sed code is always a problem. Consider, if you will, what would happen if `OU1` had the value `/; e rm -Rf * #` (hint: GNU sed has an `e` instruction that runs shell commands). For this reason, I would always prefer `awk` to do substitutions that involve shell variables:

```
cp text_file1.txt text_file1.txt~
awk -v OU1="$OU1" '{ gsub("OU=" OU1, "$$$" OU1) } 1' text_file1.txt~ > text_file1.txt
```

This avoids code injection problems by not treating `OU1` as code.

If you have GNU awk 4.1 or later,

```
awk -v OU1="$OU1" -i inplace  '{ gsub("OU=" OU1, "$$$" OU1) } 1' text_file1.txt
```

can do the whole thing without a (visible) temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

You must be careful when putting `$` inside double quotes.

```
sed -i "s/OU=$OU1/"'$$$'"${OU1}/g" text_file1.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ OU1="QA"
$ echo 'OU=QA' | sed "s/OU=$OU1/"'$$$'"${OU1}/g"
$$$QA
```