# Modify values in conf file by using shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have shell script and as part of the script I want to update the `a.conf` file (it is configuration file) which includes `key-value` pair, I want to update the values of the key. Script ask user to input the values which I am storing into variables. How could I update the multiple values in below file by using those variables. I tried `sed` but not sure how to use it for only to modify value of a particular key

a.conf file

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

I tried below `sed` command but it is not updating the `value` of given `key` -

```
sed -i -e "s/\($key1 *= *\).*/\1$newvalue/" $CONFIG_FILE
```

**Update**

If I update above command by removing space between `*=*\` then, newvalue get appended to existing value e.g. `key1=value1newvalue`

Not sure what I am missing here

Comment: Could you please confirm if it's a json file(if yes then kindly do update your question with same format)? Also please do add your tried sed code in your question, thank you.

Comment: I have update the question. This is configuration file (`.conf`), this is not a `json` file.

Comment: Kindly check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29749824/how-to-use-variables-in-sed-command if this helps you to understand how to use shell variable into sed 

Comment: Is the `T` after `$key1` supposed to be there?

Comment: Hi Dan, Sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to modify values of a particular key in a given file of format of -

```
key1=value1
key2=value2

sed -i "s/key1.*/key1=$newvalue/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I read the a.conf line-by-line and define the key and val as variables. The user is asked to input the values, which are replaced in the a.conf using sed.

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_FILE=a.conf
cat $CONFIG_FILE | while read line; do
   echo "Processing line: $line"
   key=$(echo $line | awk -F= '{print $1}');
   read  -p "Enter value for $key " val < /dev/tty
   sed -ie "s/^$key=.*/$key=$val/" "$CONFIG_FILE"
done
```

**Trial run:**

```
$ cat a.conf
key1=value1
key2=value2

$ ./script.sh
Processing line: key1=value1
Enter value for key1 test1
Processing line: key2=value2
Enter value for key2 test2

$ cat a.conf
key1=test1
key2=test2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Bash Script to update the text via sed**

This script first runs the `cd` to the location of the file and then runs the `sed` command to replace the old value `#CONFIG_PACKAGE_oui-httpd=y` with `CONFIG_PACKAGE_oui-httpd=y` in the file named `target.config`.

Logic: `sed -i 's/old_text/New_Text/' filename.sh`

```bash
#! /bin/bash
cd /target/linux/gem6xxx/xs5g01_cpe/ 
sed -i 's/#CONFIG_PACKAGE_oui-httpd=y/CONFIG_PACKAGE_oui-httpd=y/' target.config
```